Using plocate to find files which are not accesible in the file system
Suppose I have mounted filesystem which are indexed by updatedb.
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /home/me/mp
sudo updatedb

locate /home/me/mp/folder/file
# -> /home/me/mp/folder/file

Then if I unmount the filesystem and search for files with plocate, I can only get the paths for files and folders in the root of the filesystem while all the files are actually in the database.
sudo umount /home/me/mp
locate /home/me/mp/folder/file
# -> <nothing>

Why is that?
Can I make plocate to find all files in the database even if the filesystem is not mounted?
